# Drag and drop with Web Components in Safari

Tags: safari, drag-and-drop, draggable, web-component, polymer-3.x

When dragging a Web Component in Safari 11.1 (MacOS) `dragstart` is immediately followed by a `dragend` event if dragging starts on a child in the Web Component's Shadow DOM.
It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, how to enable drag and drop in Safari?

This happens for Web Components build [without external library](https://codepen.io/a-xin/pen/qKyWGz?editors=1001) as well as when [using Polymer 3](https://codepen.io/a-xin/pen/YvjKXB?editors=1001).

For example, dragging `<drag-item>` works, but dragging the included `<div class="child">` does not.

```js
import {PolymerElement, html} from 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js?module';

class DragItem extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`
      <style>
      :host {
        user-select:none; background-color: green; width: 80px; height: 80px; display: block; margin: 10px;
      }
      .child {
        background-color: red; width: 20px; height: 20px; display: block; margin: 0 auto;
      }
      </style>
      <div class="child"></div>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('drag-item', DragItem);
```

When used like this:

```html
<div>
  <drag-item draggable="true"></drag-item>
  <drag-item draggable="true"></drag-item>
  <drag-item draggable="true"></drag-item>
  <drag-item draggable="true"></drag-item>
</div>
```

[Codepen using Polymer 3 Web Components](https://codepen.io/a-xin/pen/YvjKXB?editors=1001)

[Codepen using only native Web Component](https://codepen.io/a-xin/pen/qKyWGz?editors=1001)

Comment: Filed a bug with WebKit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=186994